# How to move an icon?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, icons, font-awesome

**Code runs fine what am trying to get done is to move the Facebook icon on left of the screen instead of the middle of the screen how could I do that?**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'    





function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="col1"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook}/></div>
        <div className="col2">
          <div className="menu">
      <Link to="/about"><h3>About</h3></Link>
        <Link to="/car"><h3>Cars</h3></Link>
          <Link to="/contact"><h3>Contact</h3></Link>
            <Link to="/search"><h3>Search</h3></Link>
    <nav/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
   );
 }

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

try applying  `float: left`  on div which contains the icon.

Comment: **<nav>** tag isn't initialized you just ended it

Comment: and how could I do that? sorry for asking a dumb question just trying to learn?

Comment: also to change the color how would I go about that?